# Prioritising column in a left join SQL

Tags: sql

I am having issues with a join and I was hoping to get some help. I have one table (table A) that is structured like so:

| Fruit | SKU |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 001 |
| Apple | X01 |
| Apple | B01 |
| Banana | 002 |
| Banana | X02 |
| Banana | B01 |
| Orange | 003 |
| Orange | B03 |

For each fruit, there is a SKU that corresponds to the numbering system used in a year. There are 100s of fruits.

There is another table (Table 2) that looks like this:

| SKU_2018 | SKU_2017 | SKU_2016 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | X01 | B01 |
| 002 | X02 | X03 |

There are different SKU formats for each year between 1990 - 2020. There are no overlapping SKUs, all values are unique. However, I want to map all SKUs to one common year (2018):

What I would like is a table (Table 3) that looks like:

| Fruit | SKU | SKU_2018 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 001 | 001 |
| Apple | X01 | 001 |
| Apple | B01 | 001 |
| Banana | 002 | 002 |
| Banana | X02 | 002 |
| Banana | B01 | 002 |
| Orange | 003 | 003 |
| Orange | B03 | 003 |

My code looks like:

```
select a.fruit, a.sku, b.sku2018
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.sku = coalesce(b.sku_2018, b.sku_2017, b.sku_2016, so and so for each year)
```

however, these are returning some NULLs even when there are SKUs that match. I cannot figure out why! I hope that is clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: That is because you're using `COALESCE` and are trying to match every value with `SKU_2018` first. `X01` for `Apple` for example would not match with `001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a bad data model. You should store all SKUs in one column and have Fruit as primary key for `Table2`. You should also have another column `year` to denote when the `SKU` was assigned.

Here's what you can try:

```
SELECT a.fruit,
       a.sku,
       coalesce(b.sku_2018, c.sku_2017, d.sku_2016) as sku_2018
FROM   tab1 a
       left join tab2 b
              ON a.sku = b.sku_2018
       left join tab2 c
              ON a.sku = c.sku_2017
       left join tab2 d
              ON a.sku = d.sku_2016;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vz3Fx6qfJj6BAgZyV9uT7w/0)

Comment: Unfortunately the data was not stored by me so the data is in bad shape and I am trying to organise in a way that is usable for me. Thanks for the code - I originally had the code written this way but there were performance issues so thought there was a more efficient way

Comment: @LindaT The only way you could improve performance given that the data model remains the same is by adding indexes, filters, data distribution etc. depending on which db you're using. Otherwise, changing data model would be the best bet. Please accept answer so that it helps others.